# Uncaught AssertionError: .empty was passed non-string primitive 1

Tags: mocha.js, chai

When I give this statement as below, an "Uncaught AssertionError: .empty was passed non-string primitive 1" is thrown
expect(res.body.invoiceDetails.lineItems[0].invLineId).to.be.a('Number').and.not.to.be.empty;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the chai documentation, .empty checks weather an **array** is empty or if a **string** has a length of 0:

> .empty
>
> When the target is a string or array, .empty asserts that the target’s
> length property is strictly (===) equal to 0.

It looks like you are expecting 'res.body.invoiceDetails.lineItems[0].invLineId' to be a number so the assertion is failing.

Answer (score 5):

Try `not.to.be.null` instead of `not.to.be.empty`